# Как решить проблему в коде?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Делаю телеграм бота который принимает текст от пользователя, а бот делает из текста qrcode.
Вот код:

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
import qrcode

token = ''
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def button(message):
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    bt1 = types.KeyboardButton('Make QrCode')
    bt2 = types.KeyboardButton('Developer')
    markup.add(bt1, bt2)
    bot.send_message(chat_id, f'<b>Hello {message.from_user.first_name}!</b> <b>Choose an item: </b>',
        parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup)
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def main(message):
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        if message.text == 'Make QrCode':
            msg = bot.send_message(chat_id, "Sent text for qrcode generation:  \nAttention: if you print the text in Cyrillic, the qrcode will not be created!")
            bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, regist1)

def regist1():
    global text_qr
    text_qr =  message.text
    img = qrcode.make(text_qr)
    type(img)  # qrcode.image.pil.PilImage
    img.save("user.png")
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, 'user.png')

bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

И при проверки бота на деле вылазит ошибка :
line 34, in

bot.polling()

Comment: Попробуйте перед (на строку выше) `bot.polling` добавить `if __name__ == '__main__':` и сдвинуть `bot.polling` на 1 indent вправо.

Comment: обычно исправление ошибки начинают с прочтения полного текста ошибки, чтобы понять, в чем эта самая ошибка заключается.

Answer (score 0):

В коде было достаточно много ошибок, попробуйте заменить последние 9 строк на следующее:

```
def regist1(message):
    text_qr =  message.text
    img = qrcode.make(text_qr)
    type(img)  # qrcode.image.pil.PilImage
    img.save("user.png")
    img = open('user.png', 'rb')
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo=img)

if __name__ == '__main__':
     bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```